# Stroke not getting applied to rectangle to xml drawable used as edittext backgroun in android

Tags: android, android-edittext, android-drawable

I have a corner rounded rectangle drawale in my app which I use as a background for edittext. When I try to add stroke to the rectangle it is not getting applied. Isn't it the correct way to do it?

```
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:shape="rectangle" >
<stroke android:width="2dp" android:color="@color/d_d"/>
<solid android:color="#ffffff" />
<corners
    android:bottomLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:bottomRightRadius="8dp"
    android:topLeftRadius="8dp"
    android:topRightRadius="8dp" />
<padding android:bottom="10dp" android:top="10dp" android:left="10dp" android:right="10dp"/>
```

Comment: Your code is running perfectly!! what is color code for @d_d ?

Comment: Yeah it is running perfectly and color d_d is red not transparent so no problem there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out myself. Although I don't know reason for this but when I removed `android:backgroundTint="@color/white"` attribute from editText stroke was applied on the rectangle.